# passing a value of a link with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this code for my notification alerts.
how can i pass in the a href link the stdid value?
is it possible?
i didn't managed to make it work and i tried a some things but nothing seems to work...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.notered<?= $a?>', function() {


    $.ajax({

      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ntupdate.php',
      data: {
        "stdid": <?= $note['id']?>
      },
      success: (
        alert('<?= $note['
          id ']?>')
      )
    });

  });
})
```

```html
<a href="" name="stdid" value="<?= $note['id']?>" class="dropdown-item noti-container py-3 border-bottom border-bottom-blue-grey border-bottom-lighten-4 notered<?= $a?>">
  <i class="ft-bell info float-left d-block font-large-1 mt-1 mr-2"></i>
  <span class="noti-wrapper">
                                    <span class="noti-title line-height-1 d-block text-bold-400 info">שיבוץ חדש במערכת </span>
  <span class="noti-text"><?= $note['std_name']  ?></span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data you want from the link using jQuery's .attr() function.
The HTML for the anchor tag:

```
<a class='.myAnchor' href='#' value='shalom'>Shalom</a>
```

The javascript:

```
$('.myAnchor').on('click', function(e){
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Now you have the value and can pass it into the data however you want:

```
$('.myAnchor').on('click', function(e){
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ntupdate.php',
        data: {'stdid': value},
        success:(
             alert(value);
    )                                                                                  
});
```

});

jQuery doc:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Passing in data from a form: (provide your own url)
HTML:

```
<form class='myForm'>

<a class='.myAnchor' href=# value='shalom'>Shalom</a>
<input type='hidden' name='stdid' class='.hiddenInput value='someValue' />

</form>
```

JS:

```
//make the anchor trigger the form submit and set the input value to be the correct value
$('.myAnchor').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.hiddenInput').val('$(this).attr('value'));
    $('.myForm').trigger('submit');
});

//on form submit do the ajax call 
$('.myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //this makes the form data into a JSON object for you to use
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you tal. is it possible for you to help me with the ajax request?

Comment: the code is working grate but the problem is that on the php page i get undifinde varible on $_POST['stdid'] what can be the problem?

Comment: It is because the PHP $_POST expects data to passed in from a <form> element. So you would need to wrap your <a> with the form.

Comment: so how can i get this data on the php page?

Comment: WORKING GREAT! THANK YOU!